# JQuery JSONP cross domain call not doing anything

Tags: jquery, jsonp

Whenever I do a JSONP call through jquery to any page I set up (either locally or on my server) all I get is the silent treatment.  Firebug reports 200 OK and the response looks ok.  I setup alerts boxes to popup on success or
failure but neither appears.  It doesn't seem to matter what url I use, nothing pops up.

BUT if I use the twitter json page then I the success alert box appears as expected so there is obviously something wrong with my response but I don't know what.

As an experiment I copied the twitter json response and uploaded it to my booroo.com domain.  It should be identical, but still nothing.  I set the headers on the response page to "application/json" and utf-8 but still nothing.

Please help, I've spent all day on this now and I don't know what else to try.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
//  url: 'http://booroo.com/json.asp?callback=?',
  url: 'http://twitter.com/users/usejquery.json?callback=?',
  success: function () {
        alert("Success");     
    },
    error: function(x,y,z) {
        alert("error"+x.responseText);
    }       
});
```

The response json.asp file contains the following classic ASP headers and then the json response copied from twitter (i've tried others without any success either.)

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
Response.Expires = 0
Response.Expiresabsolute = Now() - 1
Response.AddHeader "pragma","no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "cache-control","private"
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
response.ContentType="application/json"
Response.CodePage = 65001 
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8" 
%>({"test_param":12345});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after a good nights sleep I've solved the problem.  I didn't realise these was a difference between the two response formats.  When I queried twitter just using my browser the response didn't include the function name which confused me.

```
//JSON
{"name":"stackoverflow","id":5}
//JSONP
func({"name":"stackoverflow","id":5});
```

Comment: Just as a tip, you should accept answers (like the one above, the same description of the issue and fix) rather than posting the same content over again.

Answer (score 10):

You're having issues because that's not how the response actually looks :)

When you specify `jsonp` or `callback=?` it gets replaced, it's actually doing:  `?callback=functioName`, which turns your response from something like this:

```
{"test_param":12345}
```

To this:

```
functionName({"test_param":12345});
```

*That's* needed for JSONP to work.  Check out the updated URL to see what I mean: http://twitter.com/users/usejquery.json?callback=functionName