# Why this jquery code is not working on blackberry?

Tags: jquery, ajax, blackberry, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing phonegap app using jquerymobile.

but in blackberry 9780 it does not show me alert, my code is

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', run, false);

function run(){
            $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/users/usejquery.json?callback=?', function(json){  

                alert(json.followers_count); // not displaying in blackberry
            });
        }
```

My head part is :

```
        <script src="phonegap.js">
        </script>
        <script src="jquery1.6.2.js">
        </script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile1.0b3.js">
```

It works fine in other mobiles like Android,iphone,ipad and also working on my Mozzila browser 8.0 but not working on blackberry OS 6.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: try adding `jquery1.6.2.js` before any other script

Comment: @3nigma..ok lets see what will happen....i am uploading my app on phonegap build..

Comment: @3nigma ..:( still not working

Comment: your BB device might not be supported: http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Comment: @PhillPafford...i am testing it on BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators 6.0.0...

Comment: used only jquery1.6.2.js file, comment in jquery.mobile1.0b3.js file.

Answer (score 1):

1st make sure that `run()` is getting executed, if not, then try `attachEvent` 
`element.attachEvent('ondeviceready',run)`

**Edit**

refer

[JQuery JSONP cross domain call not doing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887284/jquery-jsonp-cross-domain-call-not-doing-anything)
and
[jQuery, JSON and Apache problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396943/jquery-json-and-apache-problem)

Comment: run function is executing properly

Comment: i simply added this http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/yahoo_logo_in_061509.png image but this image is also not displaying ..it just show empty cross.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. there is a new version of jqm, the v1.0 RC1, try to work with this one.
2. Use the Ripple Emulator from RIM to test more quiccly the app, is a Chrome broser plugin.

And the most important:

deviceready needs:

1. in your body make this: `<body onLoad='initSO()'>`

then in the header, after loading: json2.js, phongap, jquery, jquerymobile... put this

```
function initSO() {
            console.log('initSO()');
           document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadySO, true); 
}

function onDeviceReadySO() {
console.log('hello word :D ');
}
```

Comment: +1 @Mariano thanks..lets see by making this changes what will happen