# Why this HTML code is not working in Blackberry?

Tags: jquery, html, blackberry, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I am developing application which will run on mobiles like blackberry,iphone and android using [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/) framework. My simple code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Phonegap app with jQuery Mobile</title>
        <script src="phonegap.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src='http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/yahoo_logo_in_061509.png' />
    </body>
</html>
```

but the issue is, Image is not displaying in blackberry mobile

It works fine in Android,iPhone mobile but not in Blackberry, it just shows not found image sign...

First application freeze for 2-3 minutes then display following screen.

[image]

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your emulator has the Internet access?

Comment: How big is the image? If it's attempting to load for 2-3 mins before failing, I'd say that suggested a timeout issue.

Comment: i have broad bank connection and image size is just 1.98 KB...its yahoo logo image

Comment: I got the image from your html code. Your internet connection is there or not?

Comment: Are you developing this application in Blackberry or Blackberry webworks?

Comment: @alishaik786..i am developing this application in Blackberry

Comment: @alishaik786..i have broad band connection

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to wrap this image in a table. It needs to have a container. Something like this:

```
<body>
    <table><tr><td><img src='http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/yahoo_logo_in_061509.png' /></td></tr>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

add permission in comfig file

Comment: <access subdomains="true" uri="*" />

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me, try to include this meta on the header, after the charset:

```
  <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, height=device-height, 
initial-scale=1.0, 'maximum-scale=1.0, 'minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" 
/>
```

I think this issue can be related with your other one here:
[Why this jquery code is not working on blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632284/why-this-jquery-code-is-not-working-on-blackberry/7643932#7643932)

Please start a webserver in the www folder of your project and use the Chrome Plugin called Ripple to test the BB app, if the image works con the Ripple plugin and not in the simulator maybe is the conection to internet of the simulator the problem.

Good Luck!